# »Feature« übersetzen oder nicht?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, word-choice, anglicism

Ist es OK, in einer auf Deutsch verfassten wissenschaftlichen Arbeit,
die sich mit Softwareentwicklung befasst, das Wort *Feature* zu verwenden? Gibt es eine Alternative? Wie könnte es übersetzt werden?

Konkret geht es um Sätze wie:

> … die neuen Features von C++11 …

Comment: Aber nimm *das* als Artikel. Duden schlägt auch *die* vor => furchtbar.

Comment: Wieso nicht weiblich, falkb?  Französische bzw lateinische Endung *-ure* / *-ura* behält im Deutschen üblicherweise ihr weibliches Geschlecht.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Feature](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Feature)* steht im Duden. Es wird allgemein verstanden werden. Demnach ist es in Ordnung, es zu verwenden.

Dazu ein Kommentar eines Mitarbeiters der Rechnerbetriebsgruppe der Chemie, Uni München:

> Wissen Sie übrigens, wie ich *Feature* schreibe? F, i, e, t, s, c, h, e, r.

Answer (score 2):

In der Fachwelt ist *Feature* ganz unbedenklich, da fester Bestandteil der heutzutage stark anglisierten Fachsprache, in der Informatik sowieso.
Meiner Oma würde ich den Begriff mit *Merkmal* oder *Eigenschaft* erklären, wobei mit dem Wort oft verbunden wird, dass es gleichzeitig etwas hervorstechendes ist.<sup>[(1)](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=feature&searchLoc=-1&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

> Die neuen **Besonderheiten** von C++11 ...

Je nach Kontext auch: Fähigkeiten, Möglichkeiten, Eigenschaften, Merkmale, Leistungen, ...

Comment: *Funktion* kommt auch ab und zu mal vor

Comment: Hoffentlich nimmt keiner diesen Vorschlag tatsächlich ernst - Feature kann zwar manchmal als "Besonderheit" übersetzt werden aber in diesem Zusammenhang passt das gar nicht. Das würde dann funktionieren wenn man denn vor hätte die Eigenschaften von C++ im Vergleich zu anderen Sprachen hervorzuheben, aber dies ist hier offensichtlich nicht der Fall.

Comment: @Cubic: Tja, wenn es neue Eigenschaften gibt, Methoden, Schlüsselwörter, Konzepte, Verschiedenes, dann sind sie doch etwas Besonderes schon insofern, als es sie früher nicht gab (ich weiß jetzt nicht was der Vorgänger von C++11 ist). Ein Videotutorial 'Die Besonderheiten von C++11' würde bei mir nicht mal ein Augenbrauenheben bewirken. Was stört Dich daran?